# how can i remove 0th index of the array using post method

Tags: php, arrays, session, post

i have this array

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
            [item_id] => 31 
            [quantity] => 99 
        ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
            [item_id] => 16 
            [quantity] => 1 
    ) 
)
```

and i want to unset

```
[0] => Array ( 
        [item_id] => 31 
        [quantity] => 99 
)
```

how can i do that with post method

Comment: what do you mean by post method? please explain properly [edit your question and add proper explanation]

Comment: Are you looking for something like `unset($array_name[0]);` perhaps?

Comment: @Dave absolutely yes

Comment: @SasiJarvis  pls check the answer below and let us know you got your solution or not?

Answer (score 0):

---

Hope below code will show you right direction.
your array that looks like multi-dimentional array:

```
$array = array(
    array('item_id' => 31, 'quantity' => 99), 
    array('item_id' => 16, 'quantity' => 1),
);
```

seems your `$_POST['item_id'] = 31`

You'll have to loop over all items, to analyse the `item_id`, and unset the right items :

```
foreach ($array as $index => $data) {
    if ($data['item_id'] == $_POST['item_id'] ) {
        unset($array[$index]);
    }
}
var_dump($array);
```

[live example](https://eval.in/1098306)